# How to increase tapable (hitting) area of (custom Type) UIButton without increasing size of background image

Tags: ios, ios5, uibutton

is it possible to increase tapable area of UIButton without changing size of Button's background Image

I tried:

```
[shareButton setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)];
```

&

```
[shareButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)];
```

but none of these worked.

Any Suggestion please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make the UIButton of type `buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom` and assign to it an image of a smaller size.

Do not set the image as the background image or it'll grow with the button. Set it as the main image instead.

For example if you want to set the tappable area to a 64x64 size and you want to show an image sized 32x32: the button size should be be 64x64 and the image size should be 32x32.

Programmatically:

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

// use an image with the desired size (for example 32x32)
[button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"buttonIcon.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
// just set the frame of the button (64x64)
[button setFrame: CGRectMake(xPositionOfMyButton, yPositionOfMyButton, 64, 64)];
```

Interface Builder:

[image: Interface Builder example]

Answer (score 3):

Subclass the superview of the UIButton, and override hitTest:withEvent:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint buttonPoint = [self convertPoint:point toView:_button];
    if ([_button pointInside:buttonPoint withEvent:event]) { // you may add your requirement here
        return _button;
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: is there not any other way than sub classing the UIButton? any method or property of button to set hitting area manually?

Comment: @crishoj That's much worse!

Comment: @crishoj it's not true, you can subclass the button and override pointInside.

Comment: @Andy – thanks for clarifying. I've removed the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Use the design approach you like (Interface Builder / Visual Format Language) together with Autolayout and layout the UIButton with the required size. Set title or image as content and use a transparent image with the size of the tapable area as background image.

```
_button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[_button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"contentImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Here a example with _button.layer.borderWidth = 1.

[image: Example]