# How to enlarge the touch area of an UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

How to increase tapable (hitting) area of (custom Type) UIButton without increasing size of background image

Comment: Just two possibilities: either make a custom view or make the background invisible and really big.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297467/how-to-expand-the-hittest-area-of-a-uibutton-without-extruding-its-background-i and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246452/how-to-increase-tapable-hitting-area-of-custom-type-uibutton-without-increas?rq=1

Comment: Please make some attempt to search before posting a question.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way - change contentEdgeInsets property value

```
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
```

Comment: are you sure we have to give positive value to increase the hit area ?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using icons to set in UIbutton. Then use image with 3 sizes.Like

```
  xyz.png
  xyz@2x.png
  xyz@3x.png
```

and set image xyz.png in image field not in background image.Then increase size of button.It will increase size of button not image size.